# Extremely slow WireGuard speeds?

Tags: vpn, pi-hole, wireguard

I am using **PiVPN WireGuard** and **Pi-hole** to get ad-blocking when I am not at home. I am also using it to access a web server I have setup in the LAN. My home router speeds are `~120-150mbps up/down`, and my Raspberry Pi is getting about `65mbps up/down`. When I connect to my VPN and set allowed IPs to only `10.6.0.0/24`, and the IP of my web server, I am able to access my home network at full speed. When I set allowed IPs to `0.0.0.0/0, ::/0` for extra security (my preferred method) I only get about `30mbps up/down`. I have tried to set the MTU to  `1322 + 28 = 1350` for the WireGuard client app, and even down to `1000`. I still only get about 30mbps up/down. I can access my LAN fine, just the speeds are very slow. I have been googling for the past week or so and cannot find a solution that works for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which model pi?

Comment: I am using Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB RAM on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye (32-bit)